# More than one dataset per year in ArcGIS Time Slider?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, image-mosaic, timeslider

Using a Derived/Master Mosaic dataset as a container for source raster mosaics, I have successfully enabled the Time Slider feature in ArcGIS 10.1.  The imagery on display was acquired most years between 2004-2010.   However, in the case of the year 2006 I have more than one dataset; one with leaf-off acquired in early Spring, and one with leaf-on acquired in late summer.

I would like to enable the Time Slider for both raster sets along the same time continuum with the other individual years.  So, in a perfect world I would be able to have: 2004, 2006 (spring), 2006 (summer), 2007, 2008, 2010 on my Time Slider bar.  (I intentionally left out the years for which I have no rasters: 2005, 2009).

However, in order to enable both of the 2006 sets I think I'll have to introduce a Month or even a full date rather than just incrementing by Year.  I'd prefer to not do this because it will cause the user to click 12 times more per year along the slider.

Has anyone come up with a way to enable the Time Slider to include more than one raster per year without introducing month increments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You're talking about creating a variable Time Step Interval, which the Time Slider doesn't support. All data on the slider has to be presented with the same constant, regular time step interval. If you are using one year as the interval but have two features in that year, both will appear at the same time. You either have to work with that (not an option for your case with overlapping imagery) or increase the granularity of your interval and have more steps.

Do note that you can not only change the *units* of the interval, but also the *value* as well. If you switch to months it doesn't necessarily have to be 12 more clicks per year. Set the step to 6 months and it's just two clicks per year, though that does apply to all years.

Also note that your two missing years should also be showing up as 'extra' clicks as you currently have it set up. Depending on your other settings like the Time Window, clicking those years should either be showing as blank or the previous year.

Related: [Time series animation problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132702)